# configure: error: jpeglib.h not found

Tags: php, compiling

I am trying to compile php 5.3.29 on Ubuntu 14.04. I am getting an error - `configure: error: jpeglib.h not found.`

Here is my `options.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# You can override config options very easily.
# Just create a custom options file; it may be version specific:
# - custom-options.sh
# - custom-options-5.sh
# - custom-options-5.3.sh
# - custom-options-5.3.1.sh
#
# Don't touch this file here - it would prevent you to just "svn up"
# your phpfarm source code.

version=$1
vmajor=$2
vminor=$3
vpatch=$4

#gcov='--enable-gcov'
configoptions="\
--enable-bcmath \
--with-mysqli \
--with-png \
--with-gd \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-soap \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sqlite-utf8 \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-zip \
--with-openssl \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
--with-png-dir=/usr/lib \
--with-freetype-dir=/urs/lib \
--with-zlib \
--with-gettext \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-bz2 \
--with-mysql=/usr \
$gcov"

echo $version $vmajor $vminor $vpatch
```

I've googled the error but haven't found a solution that works for me.

All help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Before this I had a line in my options.sh `--with-curl \`. I had to remove it as a temporary fix, since on compiling it asked me to reinstall curl, whereas It is already installed. I tried `sudo yum install libcurl-devel`, but it said package not found. I did not know the solution so I removed the line as a temporary fix.

Would appreciate if someone could come up with a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if you are using Ubuntu at all. `sudo yum install libcurl-devel` will not work in Ubuntu.

That said,`jpeglib.h` is provided by `libjpeg-turbo8-dev`. So install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev
```

Comment: Hi Ron, I tried the  command but it says `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8 (= 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4) but 1.3.0-0ubuntu2 is to be installed`

Comment: tried that too..here is the output `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libjpeg-turbo8 is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  apt-listchanges
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.`

Comment: after this I again tried `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev`. Still gives the same error

Comment: Are you indeed using 14.04? What's the output of `apt-cache policy libjpeg-turbo8`. Also try installing `libjpeg-turbo8` after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

`libjpeg-turbo8-dev` doesn't work anymore. It is changed to:

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-turbo-dev`